# How can I create an apple-like scroll-effect inside a sticky container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I want to create an apple-like scroll effect like this: [apple-iphone-xs-practice](http://apple-iphone-xs-practice.webflow.io/)

When I scroll inside the sticky-container on the top shared website, iPhone images will transform, based on the scroll-progress.

How can I create this in html and vanilla js?
I'm still a beginner. I would be very grateful to you for all the help you give me.

I've thought about something like...

```html
<div class="sticky-container">
  <img id="image" src="/image.jpg">
</div>
```

```js
var image = document.getElementById('image');

document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if (window.scrollY >= 1.247) {
       //Function to scale down the image based on scroll
    }
})
```

Comment: wow, you've done 99% of the hard work ... all you need is that elusive `//Function to scale down the image based on scroll`

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks, I know that, but what does such a Function have to look like?

Comment: Apparently you need to do more googling and doc reading. Here's some keywords: `scrollTop`, `css transform scale`